# Vertical Align when using flex

Tags: html, css

I am creating a header and ideally would like the title to the left and the navbar icon over to the right. I can achive this using a parent div set to `dislay: flex` with `justify-content: space-between` as seen below.

[Using Flex](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-lamport-ck78e?file=/src/App.js)

However the I cannot apply vertical align in this instance to centrally align the text and icon horizontally. I suppose I could use margin to get it looking correct but not sure if this is best approach.

On the other hand I could do something like this using `display: inline-block` however am then lost on how to postion the icon over to the right.

[Using inline-block](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-violet-49on9?file=/src/index.js)

My question is which method is better and additionally how I achive the desired functionaility so that the text sits on the left side with the icon on the right side of the viewport ensuring they are both vertical aligned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) to vertically align flex items along the Cross Axis in a row layout.

Specifically, `align-items: center` so the flex items margin boxes are centered within the line on the cross-axis. Have a look at the updated [CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-ellis-3iobv)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h4>Workbench</h4>
  <span>&#9776;</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're trying to accomplish?

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>
  Text
  </h1>
  
  <div>
  Some Icon
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `align-items: center`. Since your flex direction is row, `align-items: center` will control the vertical alignment.

```
div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 80%;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood well `align-items: center;` paired with `justify-content: space-between` should do the trick